# How can I have another markdown file and have that show up instead of readme.md on github

Tags: github

I've actually cloned a repo and built some more features on it. Now I want to add another `notes.md` file and give a brief explanation about what I have done and want to give a link to the original repo for additional documentation for others who land on my repo. How do I make `notes.md` to show it's content instead of `readme.md`. Please note that the `readme.md` file in my repos has many contributors from the original repo that was cloned, so I'am not sure if I can edit it either.

Comment: Have you tried editing `readme.md`? If you've forked the repository, you are its sole owner and can do whatever you want.

Comment: Actually not forked but cloned it. :(

Comment: So it's just a folder on your computer? Or you've just pushed it to Github? Either way, there's nothing stopping you from editing the existing `readme.md`. 

That being said, if you do intend on developing from someone else's repo, you really should fork it. That will automatically link back to the original repository.

Comment: you were right. I had to fork. Because after I cloned, added features and pushed my commits to my repo, I became a part of their contributor group. So I had to delete the repo and redo now by forking. :(

Comment: If you're worried about redoing your changes, you can take a `diff` of it with the original copy, and `patch` it on the fork.